# Are there vulnerabilities/advantages associated with a VPN service that uses only an account number, no password for authentication

Tags: authentication, vpn

The VPN service [mullvad](https://www.mullvad.net/account/create/) has an interesting (let's call it that) form of authentication, namely that all you receive is an account number, which you can pay for to receive a certain amount of time to use the service. You never get a password or any other authentication credentials.

According to [them](https://www.mullvad.net/blog/2017/1/13/clarifying-our-no-logging-policy/), they do not store any payment or personal information.

Are there any advantages for consumers to this scheme (compared to a combination of username+password)? Are there any vulnerabilities that this creates (both privacy and security-wise)? All I can think of is someone who could guess an account number could get access to the VPN for free, however the account number also allows you to manage port forwarding, but my knowledge of networks is not good enough to assess whether this could constitute a security risk).

Note: I mentioned the VPN service so I could link to their policies pages, if this is discouraged due to people shilling, editors, please feel free to remove the name/link.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with this scheme. Personally config `OpenVPN` the same way for users convenient.